# How to avoid auto forward slash IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 in Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, java-nio

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 editor. In one of my test case I am reading the file from resource folder using below method ***getClass().getResource(filename)***

I can get the path, but problem is it's always returning with extra forward slash('/') for an instance **/C:/Users/test/IdeaProjects/data.json** like this.

Due to that extra slash at 0 index. I am getting java.nio.file.InvalidPathException.

Note: this works fine in mac book, This issue is only with window OS.

Any suggestion would be reuired.

Comment: how do you get that path? Issue is not related to the editor you use I guess.

Comment: Please show your code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: *I can get the path...* It's not a path. It's a ```java.net.URL```  I would beware of mixing that up with file/path related classes and operations. More often than not, you will need ```getResourceAsStream``` not ```getResource```. Since it's a resource, forget ```File```  and ```Path```

Comment: @CrazyCoder  I am using below code 

 private String readFileToString(String filename) throws Exception {
        URL url = getClass().getResource(filename);
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(url.getPath())));
    }



If you see there url.getPath() its giving path extra forward slash

Comment: @g00se even if I use url.toURI() even though it  is working. But my question is why it is not working with url.getPath() in windows OS. Why getPath() is giving absolute path in windows and virtual path in Mac OS.

Comment: Easier ```String text = new String(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/bar").readAllBytes());``` *Why getPath() is giving absolute path in windows and virtual path in Mac OS* What is the *exact* path given by Mac?